# Why is shutdown.sh not showing the output?

Tags: java, shutdown, jboss6.x

Hi when you start Jboss 6.1 with run.sh, you have have various informations displayed and it's the same when immediately after you press ctrl-c (i am talking about Linux ), but when i call shutdown.sh i only have this as output:

> Shutdown message has been posted to the server.
>
> Server shutdown may take a while - check logfiles for completion.

How can i get the full output ?

Here are the source of the two standard scripts

```
    #!/bin/sh
### ====================================================================== ###
##                                                                          ##
##  JBoss Shutdown Script                                                   ##
##                                                                          ##
### ====================================================================== ###

### $Id: shutdown.sh 109786 2010-12-08 18:26:01Z epbernard $ ###

# Extract the directory and the program name
# takes care of symlinks
PRG="$0"
while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG="`dirname "$PRG"`/$link"
  fi
done
DIRNAME=`dirname "$PRG"`
PROGNAME=`basename "$PRG"`

GREP="grep"

#
# Helper to complain.
#
die() {
    echo "${PROGNAME}: $*"
    exit 1
}

# OS specific support (must be 'true' or 'false').
cygwin=false;
case "`uname`" in
    CYGWIN*)
        cygwin=true
        ;;
esac

# For Cygwin, ensure paths are in UNIX format before anything is touched
if $cygwin ; then
    [ -n "$JBOSS_HOME" ] &&
        JBOSS_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JBOSS_HOME"`
    [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] &&
        JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
fi

# Setup JBOSS_HOME
if [ "x$JBOSS_HOME" = "x" ]; then
    JBOSS_HOME=`cd $DIRNAME/..; pwd`
fi
export JBOSS_HOME

# Setup the JVM
if [ "x$JAVA" = "x" ]; then
    if [ "x$JAVA_HOME" != "x" ]; then
        JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    else
        JAVA="java"
    fi
fi

# Setup the classpath
JBOSS_BOOT_CLASSPATH="$JBOSS_HOME/bin/shutdown.jar:$JBOSS_HOME/client/jbossall-client.jar"

if [ "x$JBOSS_CLASSPATH" = "x" ]; then
    JBOSS_CLASSPATH="$JBOSS_BOOT_CLASSPATH"
else
    JBOSS_CLASSPATH="$JBOSS_CLASSPATH:$JBOSS_BOOT_CLASSPATH"
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin; then
    JBOSS_HOME=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_HOME"`
    JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --path --windows "$JAVA_HOME"`
    JBOSS_CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_CLASSPATH"`
fi

# Execute the JVM
exec "$JAVA" \
    $JAVA_OPTS \
    -classpath $JBOSS_CLASSPATH \
    org.jboss.Shutdown "$@"

    #!/bin/sh
```

And here is the other one just to compare.
    ### ====================================================================== ###
    ##                                                                          ##
    ##  JBoss Bootstrap Script                                                  ##
    ##                                                                          ##
    ### ====================================================================== ###

```
### $Id: run.sh 111395 2011-05-18 07:45:07Z beve $ ###

# Extract the directory and the program name
# takes care of symlinks
PRG="$0"
while [ -h "$PRG" ] ; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG="`dirname "$PRG"`/$link"
  fi
done
DIRNAME=`dirname "$PRG"`
PROGNAME=`basename "$PRG"`

GREP="grep"

# Use the maximum available, or set MAX_FD != -1 to use that
MAX_FD="maximum"

#
# Helper to complain.
#
warn() {
    echo "${PROGNAME}: $*"
}

#
# Helper to puke.
#
die() {
    warn $*
    exit 1
}

# OS specific support (must be 'true' or 'false').
cygwin=false;
darwin=false;
linux=false;
case "`uname`" in
    CYGWIN*)
        cygwin=true
        ;;

    Darwin*)
        darwin=true
        ;;

    Linux)
        linux=true
        ;;
esac

# Read an optional running configuration file
if [ "x$RUN_CONF" = "x" ]; then
    RUN_CONF="$DIRNAME/run.conf"
fi
if [ -r "$RUN_CONF" ]; then
    . "$RUN_CONF"
fi

# Force IPv4 on Linux systems since IPv6 doesn't work correctly with jdk5 and lower
if [ "$linux" = "true" ]; then
   JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
fi

# For Cygwin, ensure paths are in UNIX format before anything is touched
if $cygwin ; then
    [ -n "$JBOSS_HOME" ] &&
        JBOSS_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JBOSS_HOME"`
    [ -n "$JAVA_HOME" ] &&
        JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --unix "$JAVA_HOME"`
    [ -n "$JAVAC_JAR" ] &&
        JAVAC_JAR=`cygpath --unix "$JAVAC_JAR"`
fi

# Setup JBOSS_HOME
if [ "x$JBOSS_HOME" = "x" ]; then
    # get the full path (without any relative bits)
    JBOSS_HOME=`cd $DIRNAME/..; pwd`
fi
export JBOSS_HOME

# Increase the maximum file descriptors if we can
if [ "$cygwin" = "false" ]; then
    MAX_FD_LIMIT=`ulimit -H -n`
    if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
        # Darwin does not allow RLIMIT_INFINITY on file soft limit
        if [ "$darwin" = "true" -a "$MAX_FD_LIMIT" = "unlimited" ]; then
            MAX_FD_LIMIT=`/usr/sbin/sysctl -n kern.maxfilesperproc`
        fi

    if [ "$MAX_FD" = "maximum" -o "$MAX_FD" = "max" ]; then
        # use the system max
        MAX_FD="$MAX_FD_LIMIT"
    fi

    ulimit -n $MAX_FD
    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then
        warn "Could not set maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD"
    fi
    else
        warn "Could not query system maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD_LIMIT"
    fi
fi

# Setup the JVM
if [ "x$JAVA" = "x" ]; then
    if [ "x$JAVA_HOME" != "x" ]; then
        JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
    else
        JAVA="java"
    fi
fi

# Setup the classpath
JBOSS_BOOT_CLASSPATH="$JBOSS_HOME/bin/run.jar"
if [ ! -f "$JBOSS_BOOT_CLASSPATH" ]; then
    die "Missing required file: $JBOSS_BOOT_CLASSPATH"
fi

# Tomcat uses the JDT Compiler
# Only include tools.jar if someone wants to use the JDK instead.
# compatible distribution which JAVA_HOME points to
JAVAC_JAR_FILE="${JAVAC_JAR:-$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar}"
if [ ! -f "$JAVAC_JAR_FILE" ]; then
   # MacOSX does not have a seperate tools.jar
   if [ "$darwin" != "true" -a "x$JAVAC_JAR" != "x" ]; then
      warn "Missing file: JAVAC_JAR=$JAVAC_JAR"
      warn "Unexpected results may occur."
   fi
   JAVAC_JAR_FILE=
fi

# Setup classpath 
JBOSS_CLASSPATH="${JBOSS_CLASSPATH:+$JBOSS_CLASSPATH:$JBOSS_BOOT_CLASSPATH}"
JBOSS_CLASSPATH="${JBOSS_CLASSPATH:-$JBOSS_BOOT_CLASSPATH}"
JBOSS_CLASSPATH="$JBOSS_CLASSPATH${JAVAC_JAR_FILE:+:$JAVAC_JAR_FILE}"

# Check for -d32/-d64 in JAVA_OPTS
JVM_OPTVERSION="-version"
JVM_D64_OPTION=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "\-d64"`
JVM_D32_OPTION=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "\-d32"`
test "x$JVM_D64_OPTION" != "x" && JVM_OPTVERSION="-d64 $JVM_OPTVERSION"
test "x$JVM_D32_OPTION" != "x" && JVM_OPTVERSION="-d32 $JVM_OPTVERSION"

# If -server not set in JAVA_OPTS, set it, if supported
SERVER_SET=`echo $JAVA_OPTS | $GREP "\-server"`
if [ "x$SERVER_SET" = "x" ]; then

    # Check for SUN(tm) JVM w/ HotSpot support
    if [ "x$HAS_HOTSPOT" = "x" ]; then
        HAS_HOTSPOT=`"$JAVA" $JVM_OPTVERSION -version 2>&1 | $GREP -i HotSpot`
    fi

    # Check for OpenJDK JVM w/server support
    if [ "x$HAS_OPENJDK_" = "x" ]; then
        HAS_OPENJDK=`"$JAVA" $JVM_OPTVERSION 2>&1 | $GREP -i OpenJDK`
    fi

    # Enable -server if we have Hotspot or OpenJDK, unless we can't
    if [ "x$HAS_HOTSPOT" != "x" -o "x$HAS_OPENJDK" != "x" ]; then
        # MacOS does not support -server flag
        if [ "$darwin" != "true" ]; then
            JAVA_OPTS="-server $JAVA_OPTS"
            JVM_OPTVERSION="-server $JVM_OPTVERSION"
        fi
    fi
else
    JVM_OPTVERSION="-server $JVM_OPTVERSION"
fi

# Setup JBoss specific properties
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS:+$JAVA_OPTS -Dprogram.name=$PROGNAME}"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS:--Dprogram.name=$PROGNAME}"
JAVA_OPTS="${JAVA_OPTS:+$JAVA_OPTS -Dlogging.configuration=file:${DIRNAME}/logging.properties}"

# Setup JBoss Native library path
#
if [ -d "$JBOSS_HOME/../native/lib" ]; then
    JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR=`cd "$JBOSS_HOME/../native" && pwd`
elif [ -d "$JBOSS_HOME/native/lib" ]; then
    JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR=`cd "$JBOSS_HOME/native" && pwd`
elif [ -d "$JBOSS_HOME/../native/lib64" ]; then
    JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR=`cd "$JBOSS_HOME/../native" && pwd`
elif [ -d "$JBOSS_HOME/native/lib64" ]; then
    JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR=`cd "$JBOSS_HOME/native" && pwd`
elif [ -d "$JBOSS_HOME/native/bin" ]; then
    JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR=`cd "$JBOSS_HOME/native" && pwd`
elif [ -d "$JBOSS_HOME/bin/native" ]; then
    JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR=`cd "$JBOSS_HOME/bin/native" && pwd`
fi
if [ -d "$JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR" ]; then
    if $cygwin; then
        JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR="$JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR/bin"
        export PATH="$JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR:$PATH"
        JBOSS_NATIVE_LIBPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR"`
    else
        IS_64_BIT_JVM=`"$JAVA" $JVM_OPTVERSION 2>&1 | $GREP -i 64-bit`
        if [ "x$IS_64_BIT_JVM" != "x" ]; then
            JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR="$JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR/lib64"
        else
            JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR="$JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR/lib"
        fi
        LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$JBOSS_NATIVE_DIR${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
        JBOSS_NATIVE_LIBPATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
    fi
    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$JBOSS_NATIVE_LIBPATH"
fi

# Setup the java endorsed dirs
JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS="$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed"

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java
if $cygwin; then
    JBOSS_HOME=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_HOME"`
    JAVA_HOME=`cygpath --path --windows "$JAVA_HOME"`
    JBOSS_CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_CLASSPATH"`
    JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS=`cygpath --path --windows "$JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS"`
fi

# Display our environment
echo "========================================================================="
echo ""
echo "  JBoss Bootstrap Environment"
echo ""
echo "  JBOSS_HOME: $JBOSS_HOME"
echo ""
echo "  JAVA: $JAVA"
echo ""
echo "  JAVA_OPTS: $JAVA_OPTS"
echo ""
echo "  CLASSPATH: $JBOSS_CLASSPATH"
echo ""
echo "========================================================================="
echo ""

while true; do
   if [ "x$LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND" = "x" ]; then
      # Execute the JVM in the foreground
      eval \"$JAVA\" $JAVA_OPTS \
         -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"$JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS\" \
         -classpath \"$JBOSS_CLASSPATH\" \
         org.jboss.Main "$@"
      JBOSS_STATUS=$?
   else
      # Execute the JVM in the background
      eval \"$JAVA\" $JAVA_OPTS \
         -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"$JBOSS_ENDORSED_DIRS\" \
         -classpath \"$JBOSS_CLASSPATH\" \
         org.jboss.Main "$@" "&"
      JBOSS_PID=$!
      # Trap common signals and relay them to the jboss process
      trap "kill -HUP  $JBOSS_PID" HUP
      trap "kill -TERM $JBOSS_PID" INT
      trap "kill -QUIT $JBOSS_PID" QUIT
      trap "kill -PIPE $JBOSS_PID" PIPE
      trap "kill -TERM $JBOSS_PID" TERM
      if [ "x$JBOSS_PIDFILE" != "x" ]; then
        echo $JBOSS_PID > $JBOSS_PIDFILE
      fi
      # Wait until the background process exits
      WAIT_STATUS=128
      while [ "$WAIT_STATUS" -ge 128 ]; do
         wait $JBOSS_PID 2>/dev/null
         WAIT_STATUS=$?
         if [ "$WAIT_STATUS" -gt 128 ]; then
            SIGNAL=`expr $WAIT_STATUS - 128`
            SIGNAL_NAME=`kill -l $SIGNAL`
            echo "*** JBossAS process ($JBOSS_PID) received $SIGNAL_NAME signal ***" >&2
         fi
      done
      if [ "$WAIT_STATUS" -lt 127 ]; then
         JBOSS_STATUS=$WAIT_STATUS
      else
         JBOSS_STATUS=0
      fi
      if [ "$JBOSS_STATUS" -ne 10 ]; then
            # Wait for a complete shudown
            wait $JBOSS_PID 2>/dev/null
      fi
   fi
   # If restart doesn't work, check you are running JBossAS 4.0.4+
   #    http://jira.jboss.com/jira/browse/JBAS-2483
   # or the following if you're running Red Hat 7.0
   #    http://developer.java.sun.com/developer/bugParade/bugs/4465334.html
   if [ "$JBOSS_STATUS" -eq 10 ]; then
      echo "Restarting JBoss..."
   else
      exit $JBOSS_STATUS
   fi
done
```

Comment: A quick and dirty way to make any `sh` script be more verbose is `sh -x shutdown.sh`.

Comment: I did that to check but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The JBoss shutdown script just posts a shutdown message to the server. The log that you get when you originally started the server (log file, console etc) will continue to log info while shutting down.

Answer (score 0):

The `org.jboss.Shutdown` class is *designed* to not output anything to the console.  What you are seeing is all that the program will ever output.  If you need more information, check the log files.  And if that is not enough, consider adjusting the JBoss logging level.

---

You can confirm this by looking at [the source code](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/4.0.2/org/jboss/Shutdown.java.html).

Note that this program doesn't do the shutdown.  What it actually does is to send a request to the server to tell it to shutdown.  The server takes care of the rest ... asynchronously.